# using theme_menu_link()

Tags: routes, theming

I am currently using [`theme_menu_link()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) but it themes every menu in Drupal. I only want to theme my main menu. How can I check for a specific menu?

```
function theme_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

//if(id == main_menu){ theme it different } 

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";

}
```

Comment: What do you need to do differently?  And are you talking about the link elements themselves (the <li>) or the elclosing menu (the <ul>)?

Comment: yes,basically i want to add a div inside the <li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the ID of a menu by looking at the URL when you edit it in the menu configuration admin interface and converting dashes to underscores.

For example, on `admin/structure/menu` if I hover 'User Menu' I see `admin/structure/menu/manage/user-menu/edit` which means that the menu machine name is 'user_menu'.

The `$element` contains the menu's id: `$element['#original_link']['menu_name']`.

So you can put that in your `if()` and get

```
if($element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == 'user_menu') {
  ...
}
```

where you replace 'user_menu' with the name of the menu you want.

Comment: thanks this is what i wanted. but i forgot i am using Nice Menus Module. Do you know how I can theme these <li>'s instead?

Comment: I am not very familiar with that module. I think this would be a separate question.